# Place a button above a table cell and vertically align the text in the cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a button above a table cell, here's what I've achieved:

[image]

This is the code:

```css
body {
    margin: 100px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

td span {
    text-align: center;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#btn {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button id='btn'>test</button>
            <span>Alfreds Futterkiste</span>
        </td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That looks good, I've placed the button above a table cell. But here's one thing bothering me: the text in the first table cell is not vertically aligned. Why? I've used `vertical-align` but it doesn't work. How to make it work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Detach the btn from the DOM flow with `position: absolute` so it's not calc'd in the measurement like so;

```css
body {
    margin: 100px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

td span {
    text-align: center;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#btn {
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.pos-relative {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="pos-relative">
            <button id='btn'>test</button>
            <span>Alfreds Futterkiste</span>
        </td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

table {
  width: calc(60vw - 2rem);
  height: calc(60vh - 3rem);
  margin: 2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

td {
  padding-top: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
}

.over-top {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.over-left {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -2.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.over-right {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -2.5rem;
  text-align: right;
}

button {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="over-top">
        <div class="over-left">
        <button>X</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="over-top">
        <button>X</button>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="over-top">
        <div class="over-right">
        <button>X</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

GRID Example:

```css
body{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1rem 1rem repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: .1rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.cell { border: 1px solid #000; }

.row-1{ grid-row: 2 / 4; }
.row-2{ grid-row: 4 / 5; }
.row-3{ grid-row: 5 / 6; }

.col-1{ grid-column: 1 / 4; }
.col-2{ grid-column: 4 / 7; }
.col-3{ grid-column: 7 / 10; }

button { grid-row: 1 / 3; grid-column: 2 / 3; }
```

```html
<div class="cell row-1 col-1"></div>
<div class="cell row-1 col-2"></div>
<div class="cell row-1 col-3"></div>
<div class="cell row-2 col-1"></div>
<div class="cell row-2 col-2"></div>
<div class="cell row-2 col-3"></div>
<div class="cell row-3 col-1"></div>
<div class="cell row-3 col-2"></div>
<div class="cell row-3 col-3"></div>
<button>X</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position absolute in the button and position relative in parent td.

```css
body {
    margin: 100px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

td span {
    text-align: center;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#btn {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    top: -10px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="position: relative">
            <button id='btn'>test</button>
            <span>Alfreds Futterkiste</span>
        </td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```